# Why is n^log5 the same order as 5^logn , I would assume 5^logn would be the higher order

Tags: math, big-o, complexity-theory

how are n<sup>log5</sup> and 5<sup>logn</sup> of the same order?

Knowing that n<sup>2</sup> < 5<sup>n</sup> i would assume that n<sup>log5</sup> < 5<sup>logn</sup>

Comment: Why would you assume that? Also, how is this directly related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

This is because if you follow logarithmic laws you see that they are the same, following this:
[image]

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer in text form. Don't use images for the main parts of your explanation

Comment: If you start by 'assuming they are the same', you need to _be explicit_ about checking that the implication goes both ways at every step. Alternatively, just give the reverse derivation: start from a clearly-true statement and proceed to your desired conclusion.

Comment: thank you! So you apply log to both then use the log rule log(m^k) = klog(m)

Comment: @shrekti please mark my answer as the right answer

Answer (score 1):

`a^b = e^(b*log(a)) = (e^b)^(log(a)) = (exp(b))^(log(a))`.

The first equality is a definition, the second one is a well-known rule on powers, the third one is just a notation.

With `a=5` and `b=log(n)` this gives

```
5^(log(n)) = (exp(log(n))^(log(5)) = n^(log(5))
```

because `exp(log(n))=n`.